# Karma finds no test files on start but finds every file when reloading

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-cli

I have an Angular 4 project with jasmine tests and the Karma test runner. I started from DavideViolantes starter ([github](https://github.com/DavideViolante/Angular-Full-Stack)) and have had a good experience changing it to suit my needs.

The last few days I have spent a lot of time writing tests and I test the Angular component separately from my models with separate Karma config files. I started writing the model tests and everything worked fine. Then I wrote the component tests and they worked fine as well. But then I noticed a strange behavior in the model tests.

When I run `ng test` for the model tests (with the correct karma.conf.js given explicitly) no test files are found. The webpack context object is empty and the browser shows "0 specs, 0 failures".

If I then touch a watched file the webpack context is loaded with all the test files and the browser shows every test.

My only guess is that something is happening too late and therefore is in place for the second run.

The log shows no errors. The config file is basically identical with the one for the component tests.

Any debugging tips?

**karma.config.js:**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '..',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine-html-reporter',
      'karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter',
      '@angular/cli/plugins/karma',
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: 'common/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'common/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

**test.ts:**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare var __karma__: any;
declare var require: any;

__karma__.loaded = function () {};

getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
context.keys().map(context);
__karma__.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got a similar problem. I’m working with two source folders. Therefore I have implemented the context, in order that it will be searched in two folders.

```
const context = require.context('../', true, /\/(@modules|src)\/.*\/.*\.spec\.ts$/);
```

If I’m starting ng test, only tests from 'src' folder will be found an run. If I start the test again through a watcher, all tests (src & @modules) are found.

It is crazy, that an abort with „Error in“ comes with the third reload and with the fourth reload everything is found again and running. These two conditions repeat with every other reload. Can I use ng test only with every „straight“ run reliably? Could be difficult to define in my Jenkins environment.

BTW I can exactly replicate the same problem. Basically whenever the tests are not in the default source folder.

Comment: In my case it works, when I move die @modules folder inside die src folder.
See: https://github.com/netTrek/angular-cli-issues/tree/works
But it would be much cooler, when we could use more then one source folders.